# IIS 7 Applications and asp.net - newbie question

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-3.5, application-pool, pipeline

Just getting started on a project to migrate from win 2003 iis6 to win 2008 / IIS7, and after reading the MS documentation and also various articles I am a little confused, as it states a site needs to have one or more applications.

However I have setup a new site pointed at my .Net 3.5 directory and it works.

This means that ....

A- I am seeing things.
B- A site does not actually need one or more applications.

Can anyone explain the above behaviour? and or point me to any useful articles that explain site, applications etc... to me.

The app pool is in classic pipeline mode, not sure if this is a problem.

Many thanks,

Comment: your site already has a defined application that runs in its own pool.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess in a comment is correct - a web site itself also acts as an application and does not require an explicit application subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some links that helped me with understanding IIS 7.0

[Configuration reference](http://www.iis.net/configreference)
[Operation Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732976%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, there certainly some useful info there that will come in handy going forward.

Comment: After doing some further reading I beleive that the answer is that each website has a default root application.

I was being thrown off by there not being an application node shown under the given site node in the IIS management console.

Would appreciate if someone could let me know if this is correct.